Скрипт на Lua для Rainmeter. Нужно скопировать картинку
Я пишу скин для Rainmeter. Мне нужен скрипт Lua. Нужно скопировать картинку (имя неизвестно) из директории (которое известно) в указанную папку.

А как тогда понять, какое изображение нужно копировать, если имя файла неизвестно?

В общем мне нужно скопировать текущие обои, как правило они находятся в системной папке, но имя может быть разным. Система меняет его. Скорее всего разрешение будет jpg или png. Можно ли будет скопировать это изображение в другую папку? Нам нужно получается любой файл с расширением jpg или png скопировать в указанное место.

Тогда это, конечно, возможно.

Изображение только одно в папке?

Да, я думаю в одной.

для windows 10 скрипт может быть такой:
local user = os.getenv("userprofile")
local os_wallpaper = user.. [[/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/TranscodedWallpaper]]
local my_file = user..[[/desktop/wall.jpg]]
local h = io.open(os_wallpaper,"rb")
local content = h:read("*a")
h:close()
h = io.open(my_file,"wb")
h:write(content)
h:close()

В LUA нет копирования, но также можно использовать os.execute() и выполнить копирование средствами системы, но я бы использовал скрипт.

Да, все работает, это круто, я еще протестирую и если что напишу!)) Спасибо огромное я очень рад что есть такой форум и люди которые могут помочь!!))

Но всё-таки форум для поиска ошибок и их решения, поэтому лучше изучить LUA и самому писать скрипты, а тут уже помогут найти ошибки. Это даже не столько мое пожелание на будущее, сколько требование stackoverflow. Удачи!
